# Export Excel file in Orangehrm

Tags: orangehrm

I have using open source of orangehrm ver 3.2.2 on my Server. I want add function export data (list leave, list emp, report..) to Excel file. But I don't how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For export data in excel file, you need following steps :

1. Put a button for generate excel file. On click button send ajax request which
   is get data as per requirements.
2. after get data on server side use phpexcel library for generate excele file.
3. for generate excel file follow this example : http://www.blrf.net/blog/46/code/php/writing-excel-files-with-phpexcel/
4. save file in folder.
5. in responce, you need to send file path for download.
6. And on successfully received data, download file from responce.